# Extracting 6-8 digit dates from alphanumeric fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, ssis

Screenshot explains it all.
http://i46.tinypic.com/f3hobl.png

With the current configuration, **InvoiceSentDate** only accepts 8-digit dates (MM-DD-YY). I want to be able to capture MM-DD-YYYY dates as well. How do I do this?

For comparison, look at invoice 2106-2112 vs 2116.

FURTHERMORE, to complicate things! Some records have text after the date.
http://i50.tinypic.com/2r5qa88.png

Comment: That'll be a task in SSIS, which I know how to do.  Right now, I'm just trying to construct the SQL statement that will grab the dates cleanly.

Comment: That is going to push what TSQL will do directly.  You may need CLR and Regex.

Comment: I was also going suggest CLR and Regex.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S2

Comment: I am an absolute data noob.  Would any kind soul run me through this?

Comment: If you chose to solve this within the confines of SSIS, while you *could* craft a nasty expression in a derived column transformation to slice out the date, don't. Instead, use a script transformation and the regular expression provided by @CandiedCode/@blam would work fine in there. If you need a picture, sing out and I'll post as answer.

Comment: The ansewr Tim Lehner seems to work very well for my data set.  But if you can post the CLR/Regex method, I'd appreciate very much!  I'm always willing to learn more tricks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in pure T-SQL.  Here's the working [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4588).

Here, I am finding the date with `patindex` then finding the first non-digit after that.  This gives the params you need for `substring` to pull the date alone.  As you can see, I've added some test data which covers a variety of possibilities, including slash and dash date separators.

```
-- Test data
declare @Demo table (
    RawData varchar(100) null
)
insert into @Demo select 'JS sent via Unifier on 08/29/2012'
insert into @Demo select 'i sent via email on 09/07/12'
insert into @Demo select 'i sent via Unifier on 01/04/12; resubmitting p...'
insert into @Demo select 'JS sent via Unifier on 08-29-2012; resubmitting p...'
insert into @Demo select '08-29-2012; resubmitting p...'
insert into @Demo select '08-29-12'
insert into @Demo select 'no date here'
insert into @Demo select null

-- Actual query
select *,
    -- If there's a date, display it
    case when StartChar > 0 then substring(RawData, StartChar, DateLen) else null end as DateString 
from (
    select *,
        -- Find the first date
        patindex('%[0-1][0-9][/-][0-3][0-9][/-][0-9][0-9]%', RawData) as StartChar,
        -- Find the first non-digit after that date
        patindex(
            '%[^0-9]%', 
            right(
                RawData + '_', -- This underscore adds at least one non-digit to find
                len(RawData) - patindex('%[0-1][0-9][/-][0-3][0-9][/-][0-9][0-9]%', RawData) - 6
            )
        ) + 7 as DateLen
    from @Demo
) as a
```

**Update**

If you are just looking for 2 possible date formats you can make the query somewhat simpler by just checking for them:

```
select *,
    -- If there's a date, display it
    case
        when StartChar1 > 0 then substring(RawData, StartChar1, 10)
        when StartChar2 > 0 then substring(RawData, StartChar2, 8)
        else null
    end as DateString 
from (
    select *,
        -- Find the first MM-DD-YYYY
        patindex('%[0-1][0-9][/-][0-3][0-9][/-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', RawData) as StartChar1,
        -- Find the first MM-DD-YY
        patindex('%[0-1][0-9][/-][0-3][0-9][/-][0-9][0-9]%', RawData) as StartChar2
    from @Demo
) as a
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your answer works very well with my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The example in the link from CndiedCode is very close to what you need.

Just slightly different Regex match

N'^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$'
goes to
N'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2,4}'

The code below looks different as had to escape the \

```
    if (Regex.IsMatch("sent on 01/01/10; ex", "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4}"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Regex.Match("sent on 01/01/10; ex", "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4}"));
    }
    if (Regex.IsMatch("sent on 01/01/2012; ex", "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4}"))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Regex.Match("sent on 01/01/2012; ex", "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4}"));
    }
```

Comment: The answer from Tim appears to be a pure TSQL +1.  If things get more complex then you need to venture into regex.

Comment: I am new to SSIS and would love to see how regex is done.  Seems like some powerful, useful stuff.  Can you demonstrate this for me by any chance?

Comment: I am not an expert so all I can do is point you to where I go for reference  http://www.regular-expressions.info/  If you are going to deal with data parsing for a living then it is tool you need to have in your belt.